Hide coordinates of a dot in a label in Plotlyjs D3 chart
I am using this Plotly 3D chart as setup https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-point-clustering/
and want to show custom text on a hover label, not the coordinates + text.
In the example there's no config for this
   x: unpack(rows, 'x'),
        y: unpack(rows, 'y'),
        z: unpack(rows, 'z'),
        mode: 'markers',
        type: 'scatter3d',
        marker: {
          color: 'rgb(23, 190, 207)',
          size: 2
        }

If I add name: 'value <br>of the element', it works like so:

What I want is to get rid of the x/y/z coordinates on the tooltip.
I've checked this link https://plotly.com/javascript/text-and-annotations/ and tried to add the - mode: 'text', - but then the dots are not visible at all.
Ideally hover text would be JUST 'value <br>of the element' not next to the coordinates.
I also tried adding
      var layout = {
          yaxis: { showticklabels: false },
          xaxis: { showticklabels: false },
          zaxis: { showticklabels: false },

but that didn't help

hovertemplate: '%{data.name}',``` does the trick
